# Arabic + English text copy paste not working correclty

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, input

I am using arabic language in my application. User has the option to enter translations in particular language. I have this following text

> استبيان IQC – SSI

When I pasted this text in input text it words get shuffles english moves at the end. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/579bdu2n/1/).

```
input {
    direction: rtl;
    }

<input type="text"/>
```

Need help how can I achieve this or need to add some custom functionality.

Comment: Can you paste screen shots (or drawings) of what you expect to see, and what you are seeing? And what browser are you using?

Comment: I have added the text above I want exactly the same text when pasted inside textbox. You can check that by copy pasting above text on fiddle.

Comment: You're assuming that my browser displays the same as yours - that might not be the case (the question might look different, and the fiddle might look different, too!). Assuming that the browsers do display the same thing, if you change "rtl" to "ltr" in the CSS then it will do as you want, in this case at least.

Comment: My application is supporting right to left layout. In arabic I have scenario where there is english letter is in between.So copy pasting that text will show arabic text first but I want "rtl" + english text first is this possible?

Comment: The problem is that the English text *isn't* first - the Arabic word "istibyan" is first. In the question, the direction is LTR, so the first word goes on the left; the input box is RTL so the first word goes on the right.

Comment: Perhaps you want to have the text that the user copies from in RTL mode, so that when it is pasted it will match the original?

Comment: Yes english text can be at any position with arabic text , Is it possible to have exact text when copy pasting it using rtl direction?

Comment: The text *is* exactly the same. It's just displaying differently. When it's in a left-to-right box it displays from left to right, and when it's in a right-to-left box it displays from right to left. Do you want something that automatically detects whether the text was copied from LTR and then reverses the order of the text? What data do you actually want to be returned by the <input> field?

Comment: Basically I have right to left direction. All I have is arabic text need to be copied and paste. But some arabic text has English text in it. When we copy that it copies its arabic first and then english, all I have to do is to paste text in same formatting. Ican't explained it further

Comment: No, when you copy Arabic text with English in it, it's coming out in *exactly the same order*! It just *looks* different. The example you have above isn't "Arabic text with English in it" - it's formatted as LTR, so it's really "English text with an Arabic word in it", as far as the computer is concerned - so it actually says "istibyan IQC - SSI". When you paste it into an RTL box, it's then displayed as Arabic text, so it *still* says "istibyan IQC - SSI", but you have to start reading from the right. Did you want it to paste as "IQC - SSI istibyan"?